# ngModel, set a whole object and not only its value from ngOptios

Tags: php, javascript, object, angularjs, html-select

I just, can't figure it out how to set my `ng-model` to contain the value of the select, and not the object its self.

HTML

```
<select name="status"
        data-ng-model="search.status"
        data-ng-options="s.label for s in statuses">
</select>

$scope.statuses = [
    { label: ' - si/no - ', value: '' },
    { label: ' Migrated ', value: 0 },
    { label: ' Active ', value: 1 },
    { label: ' Canceled ', value: 2 },
    { label: ' Un-confirmed ', value: 3 },
];

$scope.search.status = $scope.statuses[0];
```

And the result would be:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [label] =>  - si/no - 
    [value] => 
)
```

Now, I just want the `[value]`, and not the whole object. How can I achieve that?

P.S. I don't want to have to access `object->value`, I just want that my `x` variable, to contain already the value.

### Update

I had this before, and it was working:

```
<select name="status" class="txt" data-ng-model="search.status">
    <option value=""> - ALL - </option>
    <option value="0"> Migrated </option>
    <option value="1"> Active </option>
    <option value="2"> Canceled </option>
    <option value="3"> Un-confirmed </option>
</select>
```

my `search.status` would contain only the selected value, and not a whole object like I get with the code above.

Comment: `$obj->value` is the notation you are looking for.

Comment: My bad, not being clear enough. I don't want to have to access `object->value`, I just want that my `x` variable, to contain already the value.

Comment: What is your x variable... maybe you mean `$x = $x->value;` or `$x = $obj->value;` I think we may need to see more code before we can offer guidance

Comment: Let me rephrase it. I expect, that my `$x` variable, to already contain the `$scope.statuses[N].value`, and having to actually access the object later on, so can finally reach my `value`. For me, `$scope.search.status` should send only the `value` and not the object its self

Comment: Okay ... i think you want `$scope.search.status = $scope.statuses[0].value;`

Comment: Actually, that doesn't work... and if it would, it would work only for the default option `[0]`, but tnx for the tip anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the markup. The `as` keyword in `ng-options` expression makes the magic.

The expression below sets object property `s.value` to the model but `s.label` still remains as the label for `<option>` element (I think it is what you want).

```
<select name="status"
        ng-model="search.status"
        ng-options="s.value as s.label for s in statuses">
</select>
```

And of course, the model value initialization in the controller has to be modified (as @Orangepill noted):

```
$scope.search.status = $scope.statuses[0].value;
```